# Is there a quick way to see what filesystem filter drivers are loaded on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows, filesystems, drivers

The question says it all, I think. I vaguely remember there was an easy way to do this, but don't remember what it was.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It doesn't provide much, but here it is:

```
C:\Windows\system32>fltmc filters

Filter Name                     Num Instances    Altitude    Frame
------------------------------  -------------  ------------  -----
MpFilter                               12       328000         0
luafv                                   1       135000         0
FileInfo                               12        45000         0

C:\Windows\system32>fltmc volumes
Dos Name                        Volume Name                              FileSystem   Status
------------------------------  ---------------------------------------  ----------  --------
                                \Device\Mup                              Remote
C:                              \Device\HarddiskVolume2                  NTFS
D:                              \Device\HarddiskVolume3                  NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolume1                  NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy12       NTFS
E:                              \Device\HarddiskVolume14                 NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy15       NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy17       NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy19       NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy21       NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy23       NTFS
F:                              \Device\CdRom11                          CDFS
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the driver's Altitude by typing

```
fltmc instances -f <driver name>
```

and then look for it in Microsoft list of assigned Altitudes:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/allocated-altitudes